# Black-Scholes model with discrete dividend payments

Tags: black-scholes, discrete-dividends

Consider the Black-Scholes model with discrete dividends in the interval $[0,T]$. This means that there's a sequence of dates such that, $$0 < t_1 < \dots < t_k < \dots < t_n < T $$ where the dividend that is paid out to the owner of the risky asset is given by, $$d_k S_{t^-_k} $$ where, $$ S_{t^-_k} = \lim_{t \to t^-_k} S_t $$ is the price of the risky asset immediately before the dividend is paid out. After the dividend payment, the risky asset price is given by, $$S_{t_k} = (1-d_k)S_{t^-_k} $$ The sequences $(t_k)_{1 \leq k \leq n}$ and $(d_k)_{1 \leq k \leq n}$ are known and $0 < d_k < 1$ , for all ${1 \leq k \leq n}$.

In this model, it is assumed that the price of the risky asset, between two dividend payment dates, is given by the usual Black-Scholes model:

$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t, \space t_k \leq t < t_{k+1} $$

for $k = 0,\dots,n$, where, by notation convenience, we introduce the values $t_0 = 0$, $t_{n+1} = T$, $d_0 = d_{n+1} = 0$, and $\mu$,$\sigma > 0$ are constant.

The price of the risk free asset, $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, is given by, $$dB_t = rB_tdt$$ where $r>0$ is also a constant.

---

The objective of this problem is to prove that there exists a Brownian motion, $(\tilde W_t)$, defined in the probability space $(\Omega,\tilde P, \mathcal{F})$, such that $$dS_t = r S_t dt + \sigma S_t d \tilde W_t, \space t_k \leq t < t_{k+1} $$

My main approach to this problem was using Girsanov's theorem.

From the geometric brownian motion, $$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t, \space t_k \leq t < t_{k+1} $$ it is known that $$S_t = S_0 e^{\big(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\big)t - \sigma W_t} $$ I also know that, $dB_t = rB_t dt$, has the following solution: $B_t = e^{rt} $. By multiplying $B_t$ on both sides of the last equation, $$B_t S_t = S_0 e^{\big(r + \mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\big)t - \sigma W_t}  $$ which has the following differential, $$ d(B_t S_t) = (r + \mu)B_t S_t dt + \sigma B_t S_t dW_t $$ which we can rewrite as, $$ d(B_t S_t) = \sigma B_t S_t \Bigg[dW_t + \frac{r + \mu}{\sigma}dt\Bigg] $$ Now using Girsanov's theorem, $$ dW_t = -\Bigg(\frac{r + \mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)dt + d\tilde W_t $$ Making the substitution in the starting geometric brownian motion, $$ dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t \Bigg[-\Bigg(\frac{r + \mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)dt + d\tilde W_t \Bigg] = \mu S_t dt - (r + \mu)S_t dt + \sigma S_t d\tilde W_t = -rS_tdt + \sigma S_t d\tilde W_t$$

---

As you can see, my calculations are not giving out the final solution desired.

My question is, did I miss a crucial step on my draft resolution that is stopping me from obtaining the desired equation? Am I not seeing something?

Furthermore, is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to divide by $B_t$ instead of multiplying. We know that the discounted price process of a traded asset ($S_t/B_t$) must be a martingale under the equivalent martingale measure ($Q$), which is the same as $S_t/B_t$ having no $dt$-term (driftless). You should use this condition to find the Girsanov kernel.

Comment: But I think the question title and first section is somewhat confusing as you are not considering the discrete dividends. You are only considering the time intervals, where there are no jumps in the process, so I am not sure why this information is relevant. The rest of the question is just standard Black-Scholes theory

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Technically, dividends are being considered while solving the problem, even though they have no influence on it. I decided to give out the initial information to see if anyone would have any better idea of how to tackle the problem using  the dividend values.